# Using async and await with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

I started using .NET4.5 for async and await. All examples seem to use the following to simulate a long term operation:

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

Now my long term calculations are really similar to:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
```

for example:

```
for(i=0;i<1000000000;i++)
    i=i*2;
```

How do I make this work with async and await? Now it seems I can 'only' use methods like webrequests, WCF, etc... with this great new method.

Where am I missing the point?

Comment: What do you mean by "my long term calculations are really similar to `Thread.Sleep`"? I wouldn't imagine they *really* sleep.

Comment: No I mean, they are blocking, like the for loop? What I basically try to achieve is to await a long for loop.

Comment: Possibly it would be better to say that the duration could be approximated using the .Sleep(3000) function instead of saying your calculations are really similar to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000))
```

Would work, but it's rather pointless

Comment: Yes but it is exactly what I needed. I can replace the Thread.Sleep with the blocking function and it works!! Thanks, seems like a stupid question, but it helps me.

Comment: You say that it is pointless, would this not help me in an async function which would normally be blocking. If you do this surly your thread can go off and do other work. Im speaking specifically with running inside IIS.